# Counting male and female in array of objects. And put counts in a new object (javaScript)

Tags: javascript

I am practicing on javascript reduce() and I have an array of objects with just name and gender properties. I make a function and used the reduce() to get the genders and make a new object like this- male: 2, female: 3
I get

> script.js:67 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'female' on
> number '1'

when i try to run it. Here is my code. Any help or a push in the right direction would be so very helpful!! Thank you so very much.

```
function genderCount(obj) {
    return obj.reduce((acc, curVal) => {
        if (curVal.gender === 'Male') {
            return acc.male = acc.male + 1;
        }
        return acc.female = acc.female + 1;
    }, {male: 0, female: 0});
}
```

Comment: Put the `return` below the  assignment, and do `return acc`. This is because the `acc` on each next iteration is always the value returned on the last iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: You could also shorten it with `const isMale = curVal.gender === "Male"; return {male: acc.male + isMale, female: acc.female + !isMale}` This is because `true` converts to `1` and `false` converts to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function genderCount(obj) {
    return obj.reduce((acc, curVal) => {
        if (curVal.gender === 'Male') {
            acc.male++;
        }
        else {
            acc.female++;
        }
        return acc;
    }, {male: 0, female: 0});
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh!!! I see now. Thank you so very much for your help. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
function genderCount (obj) {
    return obj.reduce((acc, curVal) => {
        if (curVal.gender === 'Male') {
            acc.male += 1;
        } else {
            acc.female += 1;
        } 
        return acc; 
     }, {male: 0, female: 0});
}

console.log(genderCount( [{'gender':"Male"},{'gender':"Male"},{'gender':"female"},{'gender':"female"},{'gender':"Male"},{'gender':"Male"}] ));
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for all your help. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate way that actually lets you return the count instead of an object.

```js
function genderCount (obj) {
    const male = obj.reduce((sum, curVal) => 
        sum + (curVal.gender === 'Male')
    , 0);
    return {male, female: obj.length-male}
}

console.log(genderCount( [{'gender':"Male"},{'gender':"Male"},{'gender':"female"},{'gender':"female"},{'gender':"Male"},{'gender':"Male"}] ));
```

Because the gender is always one or the other, you only really need to count one to calculate what the other will be.

So we calculate how many males there are, then we subtract that result from the total length of the array to get the female count.

It also uses JS type conversions to convert the result of `(curVal.gender === 'Male')` to a numeric value, `1` if `true`, `0` if `false`.

Comment: That is awesome slappy!! Thank you for your help.